# Can't create AVD with Google API as Target

Tags: android

In Eclipse on Mac, I installed `Google APIs` package under `Android 4.2 (API 17)`, but when I create AVD for a device `3.7" WVGA (480 x 800: hdpi)`, in `Target`, I don't have the option to choose `Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 17)`.

But in my Eclipse on Windows, that option is there.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this option on mac too, it's not that different from Windows:

[image]

Comment: thank you for confirming. after re-install and reboot, it shows up now.

Comment: I didn't have to reboot. It was enough to close Eclipse, the emulator, and the SDK Manager, and then relaunch Eclipse.